# Is it safe to place IdentityUser security stamp into unencrypted JWT token?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Normally ASP.NET Core identity places user security stamp into an encrypted cookie. For reasons of interoperability with other services I change cookie format to be a signed cookie. I wonder if having security stamp unencrypted could be a security threat.